# Why this div is going down?

Tags: html, css-float, width

Could someone explain me why the four div in this snippet is going down whenever I specify to it a fixed width? It even goes down with a width of 1 px. If I keep the width in auto it correctly appears in the same row.

```
<style>
  .au {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
  }
  .u {
    width:auto;  //change this to a fixed size like 1px
  }
</style>
<div class="au">uno</div>
<div class="au">dos</div>
<div class="au">tres</div>
<div class="u">cuatro</div>
<div>cinco</div>
```

Comment: Add display:inline-block to it. http://jsfiddle.net/RbKk3/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its simple
here you giving width:auto to .u class so its taking 100% thats why now .u class has width more than 600px(i.e sum of three div "uno" "dos" "tres" and width of charcter of fourth div "cuatro"). Due to this its displying beside third div.

At fixing widht .u class = 1px or 1px to 638px(width including charctor of "cuaro") so thats why here fourth div displying below first three divs

i cant post image otherwise i can explain by it.

for out put use below html and css code and see in browser i hope you can understand easily.

```
FIRST PHASE
.au {
float:left;
width:200px;
}
.u {
    width:100px;
}

<div class="au">uno</div>
<div class="au">dos</div>
<div class="au" style="border:red solid 1px;">tres</div>
<div class="u" style="border:green solid 1px;">cuatro</div>
<div>cinco</div>




SECOND PHASE
.au {
float:left;
width:200px;
}
.u {
    width:639px;
}


<div class="au">uno</div>
<div class="au">dos</div>
<div class="au" style="border:red solid 1px;">tres</div>
<div class="u" style="border:green solid 1px;">cuatro</div>
<div>cinco</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Nilesh, I always thought that the div that follows a floating div move completelly to the side. That was wrong, it moves only his content. :D, you open my eyes.